# Python regular expression match with file extension

Tags: python, regex

I want to use Python regular expression utility to find the files which has this pattern:

```
000014_L_20111026T194932_1.txt
000014_L_20111026T194937_2.txt
...
000014_L_20111026T194928_12.txt
```

So the files I want have an underscore '_' followed by a number (1 or more digits) and then followed by '.txt' as the extension. I used the following regular expression but it didn't match the above names:

```
match = re.match('_(\d+)\.txt$', file)
```

What should be the correct regex to match the file names?

Comment: see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Comment: Thanks. I get used to Perl style regex :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `.search()` instead; `.match()` anchors to the start of the string. Your pattern is otherwise fine:

```
>>> re.search('_(\d+)\.txt$', '000014_L_20111026T194928_12.txt')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10e8b40a8>
>>> re.search('_(\d+)\.txt$', '000014_L_20111026T194928_12.txt').group(1)
'12'
```

Comment: Thanks Martijin. This works. So even if I use '$' to indicate from the end of string, .match function doesn't search from the end?

Comment: @tonga: No; `$` is an anchor, it'll only match at the end of the string; it won't dictate where the search *begins*. You should see `.match()` as adding an implicit `^` to your pattern.